# How to check if the user is visiting the site's root url?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like to fire up some script if the user is visiting my site's root url.

For example, I want to do something in my view when the user is visiting

- `www.example.com`
- `example.com`
- `www.example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`

... [Various combinations of the above.]

And not for `www.example.com/anything else`.
What is the safest way to check this in a view page of a ASP.NET MVC 3 [Razor] web site and javascript? Also, is there any way to find out using only javascript?
Thank you.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The easiest JavaScript method is:

```
var is_root = location.pathname == "/"; //Equals true if we're at the root
```

Even `http://example.com/?foo=bar#hash` will produce the right result, since the pathname excludes the query string and location hash.

Have a look:

```
http://anything-but-a-slash/                  Root
                           /?querystring      Root
                           /#hash             Root
                           /page              Not root
```

If you have index file(s) at your root folder, have a look at the following example:

```
var is_root =/^\/(?:|index\.aspx?)$/i.test(location.pathname);
```

The previous line is using a regular expression. Special characters have to be escaped, the `/i` postfix makes the pattern case-insensitive. If you want the case to match, omit the `i` flag.

The same regular expression presented graphically:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: If you also need support for localhost try this, where the /Site/ represents the project
var is_root = (window.location.pathname == "/" || window.location.pathname == "/Site/") ? true : false;

Comment: @afreeland For `http://localhost/Site/`, `location.pathname` shows `/Site/`. If you want to test a website, temporary, you'd better use `.htaccess` to rewrite the root. See: http://pastebin.com/4ZJzKJkE. Also, `a == b` already returns a boolean, there's no need to use `(a == b ? true : false)`.

Comment: The regex will match ANY webpage beginning with `/` as root page. Check this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19473369/363573

Comment: @Alex Thanks for bringing it up. I've amended the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this more robust regular expression:

**Regex**

```
var isRoot =/^(\/|\/index\.asp|\/index\.aspx)$/i.test(location.pathname);
```

**Description**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Demo**

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/11SAXV6nOXsEhfjQ)

Answer (score 1):

Testing for pathname of "/" failed when I ran my app in debug/preview mode from my online IDE. In other words it normally is served with a clean url (no `.html`) except when I serve it from Cloud9 in which case it is served with `index.html`.

So, this is working for me:

`if(window.location.pathname.length == 1 || window.location.pathname.length == 0 || window.location.pathname === "/index.html" || window.location.pathname === "/index"){
    //I'm at the app root
}`

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression like:

`(/^https?\:\/\/[^\/]+\/?$/).test(window.location.href)`

Comment: Seems much easier to use `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: @Mic little confused with the regex can you please you brief it?

Comment: start `^`  with http `http`, may be https `s?` then ://, then anything but a / `[^\/]+`, ending with a / or not `\/?`, end of the string `$`

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if(window.location == window.location.hostname) {
    //is root
}
```

**Edit:** Do not use this, see comment

Comment: Thanks. but `window.location.hostname` does not respect port numbers. So in dev, if you're on a port number other than 80, you'll get false results.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
if (location.pathname == "/" || (window.location.href.indexOf("Index") > -1)){

  console.log("do stuff") 

}
```

be aware that the 'Index' is case sensitive